# Finding military records for Romanian pilots stationed in Jüterbog during WWII?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2, romania

I'm trying to find military records about my uncle, Chis CONSTANTIN.

As far as we know he was a Romanian pilot within Luftwaffe, who graduated from flight school in Medias, Romania, and from 1942 was stationed in Jüterbog.

Upon returning to Romania in 1948 he was imprisoned for 5 years as a political prisoner. He died in 1983.